# Why do RFCs use the term 'HTTP protocol'?

Tags: http

Several RFCs use the term 'HTTP protocol' ([example](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt)). However, the acronym 'HTTP' already includes the word 'protocol' in it. Hence, isn't it redundant (and hence incorrect) to use 'HTTP protocol', whereas the correct usage would be simply 'HTTP'?

Why do RFCs make such usage?

Comment: Perhaps the authors suffer from RAS syndrome.

Comment: For the same reason people always say "ATM Machines" when the "M" in the abbreviation is the word "Machine". This question is probably too opinion based for this site. This English Language question is related, if not a cross-site duplicate: [Examples of “ATM Machine” silly repeats?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21382/examples-of-atm-machine-silly-repeats)

Comment: Only programmers ask questions like this.  The rest of the population couldn't care less.